# Need to convert my server timestamp string to another timezone in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in java

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have an input string like :

billDate="2016-03-16T10:48:59+05:30" (please see the T in between).

Now I want to convert this to another timestamp (America/New_York).

My final result should be like 16 march 2016 or 15th march 2016 depending upon the hour value.

I saw many examples but got no hint how I can convert the above long datetime string to another string for America/New_York.
Can somebody help me on this?

I tried below code but it always gives 16 march for any hour value.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String output = formatDate("2016-03-1611T:27:58+05:30");
        System.out.println(output);

    }

    public static String formatDate(String inputDate) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
                Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(inputDate);
                return sdf.format(parsedDate);
            }
            catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle exception
            }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you parse to a `Date`, then you format that `Date`. Those are two entirely separate operations, which would use two different formatters - and you seem to have the second part done already. So your problem is really *only* how to parse your initial string to a `Date`. What have you tried for that?

Comment: I know how to parse my initial string to a date but I do not know how to convert that to different timezone timestamp

Comment: You don't convert the `Date` into a different time zone, because a `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone - you just format it with the code that you've already got, which specifies a time zone in the formatter. If you know how to parse your initial string, you should show that code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After trying I finally got the code to solve the issue:
The below code works fine:

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Test {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat fDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String output = getFormattedDate("2016-03-1611T23:27:58+05:30");
        System.out.println(output);

    }

    public static String getFormattedDate(String inputDate) {

        try {
            Date dateAfterParsing = fDateTime.parse(inputDate);

            fDateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("timeZone"));

            return fDateTime.format(dateAfterParsing);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```